# Detect if FFmpeg is running or has stopped running

Tags: c, process, ffmpeg

I'm using **C** to scan a directory which contains frames extracted by ffmpeg. Now in the event that the last file is reached during the scan, I need to check for two conditions:

1. It's the last file as the video duration is over.
2. It's the last file as ffmpeg terminated abruptly and is no longer able to populate the directory

My **C** program workflow is like:

```
while(<there exists files in the directory>)
{
   // iterate over them and do something with each frame
}

// coming out of the loop means no more files available...so I need a if condition
if(<check if ffmpeg is stopped>) // <-- need to know what to put inside the condition
{
   // start it again
}
else
{
  // video is over, nothing more left to do
}
```

I'm thinking I can do this using `Process ID` of ffmpeg, but how would I get that info? Any other alternative way of checking if `ffpmeg` has stopped?

#### Some metadata

OS : **Windows 7**
IDE : **Dev C++**
Language Used : **C**

Comment: How do you start ffmpeg?

Comment: From a batch file..and then I start this C program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely wait for `FFmpeg` process to finish. You normally obtain `ffmpeg.exe` process handle and either wait for it using [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), check its `GetExitCodeProcess` or both.

If you don't have a handle, but you do have a process identifier, `OpenProcess` will get you the handle.

Of course, you would not have to go into that trouble if you used native Windows APIs where you would be dealing with frames directly, not through files and external processes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a way to go in your case, but... in unix world a program that runs in background normally creates a publicly readable file with its process id. And then removes it when finished.

You could create this file from your batch script and then in your C program you could check if a pid from that file is running or not.

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure if Windows does the same thing too...I'll have to research on this.